# speed up Eclipse on OSX

Tags: eclipse, performance, macos

Trying to work with Eclipse for Android (ADT plugin) development at my iMac (2.4Ghz, 4Gb RAM) and it's very slow (Eclipse Galileo SR2 x64).
I know about eclipse.ini tricks and make some changes like:

> -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   -Xms256m
>   -Xmx1024m
>   -XX:+UseCompressedOops
>   -XX:+AggressiveOpts
>   -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

And use Java 1.6 by default:

> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

But still have freezing at small project. Even scrolling of class with 50LOC very slow. At same projects IntellijIdea works much faster.
Have some secret spells to win?

Comment: Did you try an `eclipse.ini` like this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the best way to keep eclipse performant is to use as few plugins as possible.

To that end, I keep totally separate eclipse installations for different development tasks (one for Android, one for Python, etc.).

Rather than using one of the prescribed distributions (like "Eclipse for Java developers"), I always start with a [PDE](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) installation (i.e., basically no plugins). Then I add only the plugins that I need for the particular task.

I find that startup time, memory usage, and performance are a lot better. None of my environments require more than 200MB of RAM, even with lots of big projects open. Also, no need to mess with `eclipse.ini`.

As an added bonus, the PDE download is a mere 50MB, not 100-200MB for the standard distributions.